# Android: Create an image from template + form data

Tags: android, image, canvas

In my project I'm using a simple form fields such as image,name,company,venue,datetime which are being entered by the user. But before entering their details I provide template choice section to the user which contains three predefined invitation card templates(image). 
I want all the details of the user that was filled, to be embed into the invitation card template(image) that he selected and lastly I could show a final image containing all the details entered and that too on the invitation card template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//template is the card template, strings is the details, x and y are the locations of the strings.
//The top left corner of the image is (0, 0), and the bottom right is (template.width, template.height)
private static Bitmap makeDetailedBitmap(final Bitmap template, final String[] strings, final float[] x, final float[] y)
{
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(template.getWidth(), template.getHeight(), template.getConfig());   //Create the base image
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);   //Create a canvas so we can draw onto the base image
    canvas.drawBitmap(template, 0, 0, null);   //Draw the template

    //EDIT: Forgot to set the text paint
    Paint p = new Paint();
    //p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);   //Uncomment if you want centered text
    p.setTextSize(12);   //Change as you please
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);   //Change as you please

    final int len = strings.length; //Assumes that the length of x and y are >= the length of strings
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        canvas.drawText(strings[i], x[i], y[i], p);  //Draws text onto image
    }
    return result;   //Returns image that was modified using the canvas (aka image with details)
}
```

So just call this for each template you want.

Comment: How could I define the position or assume it to be the place where I want the "NAME" to be inserted

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi   It really depends on how you want it laid out. If you want a standard top-to-bottom, you could set all of the X's to 5, and make the Y's count by 20's, starting at 5 (5, 25, 45, 65, etc., but it really depends on your text size). The text will be cropped if it exceeds the template's borders. Btw, I updated my answer to include text paint.

Comment: I'm facing a difficulty. Actually one of my text is too long and I need to place in centre of screen which is working good. But the text just exceeds the bitmap and is overflowed. Is there a way to auto change the line when the text exceeds with a condition that it the word won't break up

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi You can use the paint's measureText(string) method to get the width of the text. So you can check if the X coordinate plus the width is greater than the bitmap's width, then you can change the text alignment